# python large file parsing

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1GB log file(.txt) in the following format,

```
[ABC] [12.45] [bla bla bla] [12345]
[DEF] [12.45] [bla bla bla] [12345]
```

I am trying to parse it into arrays for each of the [].
So far, I have tried numpy.genfromtxt and also reading line by line by opening the file.
numpy gives some MemoryError with 1GB file. the lin-by-line method takes  about 35 secs.

Is there any other library or way to fasten the parsing?

Reading line by line:

```
with open(filePath) as f:
    for line in f:
        splits = findall('\[(.*?)\]', line)
        A.append(splits[0].strip())
        B.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(splits[2], '%H:%M:%S.%f'))
        C.append(splits[4])
```

Comment: Do you know specifically what's the size of each line in bytes?

Comment: @RafaelBarros: Nope that will vary.

Comment: What do you want this for? Do you need random access? Do you use every line?

Comment: You said you read it line by line. I am curious of your code to do the same. Can you update your post?

Comment: @Veedrac: Once I have these in arrays, I do some processing and then plot the timing and processed data.

Comment: Can you do the processing in one pass? If so, you won't need to keep the entire log in memory. That alone might speed things up a lot.

Comment: @user2626431 do you need to all data at once? can you process while you're reading the data? you could setup 2 processes in a pipeline (parser, processing) - this would prevent stalls on io waits and allow you to process the data while waiting for the disk. Giving us some more information about the "processing" step should make it easier to give an answer.

Comment: This is not nearly enough info to give you an answer, but the easiest suggestion is to move the file to an SSD disk (raw reading speed on my system is 1.7 secs for a 1GB file from SSD and 7 secs from a spinning disk).  You don't say what an acceptable speed is for you, so addressing the inefficiencies in your parsing code is premature (if you need to get under 7 secs on a spinning disk, then maybe Python isn't the right tool..)

Comment: Have you tested how long it takes if you remove those `append` lines and just read the lines and `findall`? Or if you also remove the `findall`? Without profiling, optimizing is impossible. It's quite possible that reading and parsing the file only takes 2 seconds, but allocating a few gigs of memory and swap-thrashing adds another 33 seconds, in which case the answer implied by Veedrac, Robᵩ, and viraptor's comments is almost certainly the answer if possible (and, if not, a different answer using, maybe, `dbm` or `sqlite3` is). Or maybe the parse is the slow part. Who knows until you test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can speed up the parsing significantly by using `str.split` instead of `re.findall`.

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        splits = line.split('] [')
        A.append(splits[0][1:])
        B.append(splits[1])
        C.append(splits[2])
        D.append(splits[3][:-1])
```

Comment: Thank you! that was the culprit.